# nginx -t error: [emerg] "default_type" directive is duplicate

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Had a copy+paste Nginx config for a server running multiple WP sites with super slow page loads. Ran and configured MSQL and Apache using Apachebuddy.pl

Nginx wouldn't restart due to the above errors and, after an inadvertent server restart, the following error is present:

> Error: Unable to make action: Unable to manage service by nginxmng: ('start', 'nginx'). Error: [2016-03-22 22:14:01] ERR [util_exec]
>   proc_close() failed ['/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/nginx_control'
>   '--start'] with exit code [1]  Can not start proxy server:
>   /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/nginx-config execution failed: nginx:
>   [emerg] "default_type" directive is duplicate in
>   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:32 nginx: configuration file
>   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Here is erroneous nginx.conf

```
#user nginx; worker_processes 1;
#error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log; #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log     notice; #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
#pid /var/run/nginx.pid; 
events { worker_connections 1024; } 
http { #include mime.types; default_type application/octet-stream;
 #log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" ' # '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ' # '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
 #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
 sendfile on; tcp_nopush on; types_hash_max_size 2048; server_names_hash_bucket_size 64; include /etc/nginx/mime.types; default_type application/octet-stream;
 keepalive_timeout 10;
 tcp_nodelay on; 
 gzip on; gzip_vary on; gzip_proxied any; gzip_comp_level 9; gzip_buffers 16 8k; gzip_http_version 1.1; gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
 #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)"; include /etc/nginx/*.custom 
 server_tokens off; 
 location ~* .(ico|jpg|webp|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|bmp|zip|woff)$ { access_log off; log_not_found off; add_header Pragma public; add_header Cache-Control "public"; expires 14d;
 location ~* .(php|html)$ { access_log off; log_not_found off; add_header Pragma public; add_header Cache-Control "public"; expires 14d;
 fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=stupidfast:16m max_size=1024m inactive=60m;
 fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie; fastcgi_pass_header Cookie; fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie; fastcgi_index index.php; fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
 fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info; fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info; fastcgi_intercept_errors on; include fastcgi_params; fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache; fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache; fastcgi_cache drm_custom_cache; fastcgi_cache_key $server_name|$request_uri; fastcgi_cache_valid 404 60m; fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m; fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 4m; fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating;
 fastcgi_pass localhost:9000; { override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile #include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite explicit. You have:

```
default_type application/octet-stream;
```

in the `http` block of your configuration file **twice**.

Remove one of them.